# Use of whipping cream in fudge

Tags: fudge

A UK fudge chain uses whipping cream in their fudge (I assume instead of butter). How much should one use and whats the benefit?

Comment: *Whipped* or *whipping* cream?

Comment: It's the Fudge Kitchen and they use Whipping Cream.