# Commercial fudge recipes

Tags: fudge

A book "the 50 best fudge recipes" advise from scaling up the recipes. Does anyone know of any commercial scale fudge recipes or can the recipes simply be increased proportionately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They advice against scaling, because cooking a batch twice as large will take more than twice as long. Nothing terrible will happen if you scale a recipe, but you will likely spend hours waiting by the stove for your fudge to reach the correct temperature. It's faster to just cook several small batches one after the other, or making several in parallell in different pots.

Comment: So how long does it take for the professionals to do?

Comment: @Antony I would guess that large factories have machines to do the stirring, so it doesn't matter if it takes 12 hours to complete a huge batch, and exclusive, handmade fudge is made one (or several) small batches at a time, so it take no longer per batch than it takes you. As far as I know, there is no universal method all professional fudge makers use.

Comment: my mistake - sorry by commercial for this whole question I mean the typical fudge shop - ie the makinac island fudge shops :o)

Comment: @Antony Based on the pictures on various websites, it seems they make one huge batch at a time. I suppose it is less of a concern that it takes several hours of stirring to get it to the right temperature if making fudge is you actual job :) I can't say anything more specific than "several hours" though, and unless you can get hold of someone who works in a fudge shop or experiment yourself, I doubt you can get anything more exact. Home cooks typically don't even *want* 3 gallons of fudge, and therefore only make small batches.

Comment: I recently visited a fudge shop who said the whole process (for their batch) takes 2.5 hours!! Thanks for your answer which is the answer.